# How can i change the color of text in flat list when there is change in state data

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to dynamically change the color of Text inside flatlist,

I have the below code. I am trying to change the value based on some fetch data.

I guess as the list is already loaded its not effecting the css.

is there any way to to change the color based on the this.state.colored change

I have checked the if condition in the fetch it is giving me alert, which means the data is changing but not getting updated to flatlist

```js
    export default class UnaddingScreen extends Component {
     
      componentDidMount() {
        this.timer = setInterval(() => this.getData(), 3000);
      }
      // const ds = ''
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        let values = this.props.data;
        array= JSON.parse(values);
      //  alert(array);
        this.state = {
          data: array,
          colored:'#192034'
        };
      }
    
      async getData() {
        const timeout = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(reject, 300, "request timed out");
        });
    
        const request = fetch("http://localhost:3000/adrChannel", {
          method: "GET"
        });
    
        return Promise.race([timeout, request])
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseData => {
            //set your data here
            //  jsondata = responseData;
            //  if(responseData.coData.coData) {
    
                if(this.state.data.find((rec) => responseData.coData.coData == rec)){
                  //alert(responseData.coData.coData);
                  this.state.colored='#3C0006';
                }
    

            //  }
          })
          .catch(error => alert(error));
      }
    
      render() {
        const percentage = 40;
        return (
          <View style={styles.base}>
    
              <FlatList
                containerStyle={{alignItems: "flex-start",width: '100%',position:'absolute',top:30}}
                ListHeaderComponent={() => <Text style={styles.text}>Unadding Started</Text>}
                data={this.state.data}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
    
                    <Text style={styles.text,{
                    backgroundColor:this.state.colored,
                    alignItems: "flex-start",
                    fontSize: 38,
                    color: "lightblue",
                    justifyContent: "flex-start",
                    height: 40,
                    borderColor: '#232C46',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    marginTop: 10,}}>{item}</Text>
    
                )}
    
              />
    
    
            <RNSlidingButton
              style={styles.slider}
              height={60}
              onSlidingSuccess={this.onSlideRight}
              slideDirection={SlideDirection.RIGHT}
            >
              <View>
                <Image
                  resizeMode="cover"
                  source={require("../../images/movingballt1.png")}
                />
              </View>
            </RNSlidingButton>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      image: {
        marginTop: 120,
        position: "absolute",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
    
      },
      base: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#010A13"
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

react will re-render only when state changes i.e after calling `this.setState`

modify your promise like below

```
    return Promise.race([timeout, request])
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        //set your data here
        //  jsondata = responseData;
        //  if(responseData.coData.coData) {

            if(this.state.data.find((rec) => responseData.coData.coData == rec)){
              //alert(responseData.coData.coData);
              //this.state.colored='#3C0006';
              this.setState({ ...this.state, colored: '#3C0006' });
            }


        //  }
      })
      .catch(error => alert(error));
```

Comment: thanks for help, with that every element in the list is changing the color, i guess I need to make some changes to change it back to previous color for every operation

Answer (score 0):

You should use class based styles. Declare classes in your CSS that will give you the colors you want. Then when you get your data, use your logic to add the appropriate class to the elements you want to change the color of.